# Site uses Javascript and I am having trouble accessing it using htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am trying using a Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight App to scrape data from [PlayStation](https://store.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/#!/en-us/free-games/cid=STORE-MSF77008-PSPLUSFREEGAMES?smcid=pdc:us-en:ps-plus:sub-nav-new-arrivals).

However, I believe the site uses Javascript and I am having trouble accessing it using htmlagilitypack.

My code so far is:

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
   string htmlPageLive = "";

   using (var client = new HttpClient())
   {
      htmlPageLive = await client.GetStringAsync("https://store.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/#!/en-us/free-games/cid=STORE-MSF77008-PSPLUSFREEGAMES?smcid=pdc:us-en:ps-plus:sub-nav-new-arrivals");
   }

   HtmlDocument htmlDocumentLive = new HtmlDocument();
   htmlDocumentLive.LoadHtml(htmlPageLive);

   foreach (var div in htmlDocumentLive.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class= 'pane pane0']"))
   {
      PSPGames newGame = new PSPGames();
      newGame.Title = div.SelectSingleNode(".//h3[@class= 'cellTitle']").InnerText.Trim();
   }
   lstPSPGame.ItemsSource = PSPgame;
   customIndeterminateProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

However, the app is crashing on the 'foreach' line when it tries to look up the node 'pane pane0'.

Is it possible to scrape the data? If so, what would I need to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to scrape the data with HtmlAgilityPack since it is loaded asynchronously. What you get when querying the page is its skeleton.

What you could try is watch the network calls and see if a public webservice is called. Look out for json or xml data

Comment: Done that.  The calls made https://ajax.googleapis.com:443 and https://auth.api.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com:443

Comment: @kkerswell Did you find the data in a different call (I'm behind a proxy that won't let me check the page, I can't really go see what's behind these links)

Comment: Nothing that I can decipher no.

Comment: Have a look at this JSON data, this is what you need apparently, need to dig into it to get the games list: https://store.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/chihiroview/viewfinder?https%3A%2F%2Fstore.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com%2Fstore%2Fapi%2Fchihiro%2F00_09_000%2Fcontainer%2FUS%2Fen%2F999%2FSTORE-MSF77008-PSPLUSFREEGAMES%3Fsize%3D30